# How to install rpm package from pbone.net?

Tags: rpm, ansible, epel

I need to install `ansible-2.1.0.0-1.el7`. It was always in the epel repo and it was the latest release I just had to do:

```
yum -y --enablerepo=epel install ansible
```

It was all fine. But now the this ansible is version 2.2 which I can't use.
So I need to find another way to install it. The old version is not in the epel repo anymore.
I saw the package [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/34462744/dir/redhat_el_7/com/ansible-2.1.0.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm.html) on pbone.net. Now my question is:
Which command do I need to perform to download & install this rpm package from here?

Comment: Why do you say you can't use ansible 2.2?

Comment: Looks like rpm.pbone.net no longer indexes this version, as well as many other repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you need to pin an old version of a package, you should mirror it so you have it accessible.  Otherwise, you'll run into problems exactly like this.

Rather than installing binary packages from untrusted community mirrors, I'd recommend choosing another one of [the install options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html) for Ansible.  You could [install with pip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-pip), which [allows specifying a version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13916850/120999).  Or you could [download a tagged release](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#tarballs-of-tagged-releases) and [install from source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source).  Either of these should keep archives around forever (theoretically, you may still want to mirror it) and will be more secure as well.